Can we construct an Ising model with non-classical properties?
I am interested in an Ising model whose hamiltonian has an stochastic component. That is, the system is assigned a probability of interacting in a certain way and another probability of interacting in another way. This system could be written as a vector hamiltonian and one could use quantum formalism to describe it or proyect it in a extra dimension.
My question is: although we are using these physical representations of a non-physical system, what can we say about the first non-physical system?

Are you thinking about something similar to Heisenberg model?

Can you explain what is being determined randomly in a little more detail? Physicists have considered a lot of variants of the Ising model
